# How to create 2D vector flow field from components in 2 different .vtk files in Paraview?

Tags: paraview

I am rather new to Paraview and have been reading a bit about vector plotting techniques to indicate flow direction and velocity magnitudes. I am quite stuck, however, with my 2 files.

These are both .vtk files of the magnitude of the x and y components of a surface velocity field of a glacier. What I would like in the end is just a field of arrows which point in the direction of the flow and whose size correlates to the velocity magnitude. I have read about stream tracer but it stays greyed out for me. I wonder if anybody can help me or at least give me some guidance about how this can be done. Thanks!

x component: veloc_x.vtk - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VpFKe_my_Ep0rt80CIcw4B8xNi3AwiSE/view?usp=sharing

y component: veloc_y.vtk - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eP4FgSZMO-bEZQJzKSbLuTl90zxbxlsh/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The steps are as following:

1. load both files
2. select them, use `Append Attributes` filter
3. `Merge Vector Components` to put X and Y in a vector.

You may want to use `Calculator` to create a `Z` array containing only `0` before step 3. because `Merge Vector` expect 3 components.

Then use the `Glyph` representation to setup the arrows in the vector field.